# Passport-jwt token expiration

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, jwt

I am using passport-jwt to generate my tokens but I noticed that the tokens never expire, is there any way to invalidate a particular token according to a rule set for me, something like:

```
'use strict';
const passport = require('passport');
const passportJWT = require('passport-jwt');
const ExtractJwt = passportJWT.ExtractJwt;
const Strategy = passportJWT.Strategy;
const jwt = require('../jwt');
const cfg = jwt.authSecret();

const params = {
    secretOrKey: cfg.jwtSecret,
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader()
};

module.exports = () => {
    const strategy = new Strategy(params, (payload, done) => {
        //TODO: Create a custom validate strategy
        done(null, payload);
    });
    passport.use(strategy);
    return {
        initialize: function() {
            return passport.initialize();
        },
        authenticate: function() {
            //TODO: Check if the token is in the expired list
            return passport.authenticate('jwt', cfg.jwtSession);
        }
    };
};
```

or some strategy to invalidate some tokens

Comment: Could you solve it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The standard for JWT is to include the expiry in the payload as "exp".  If you do that, the passport-JWT module will respect it unless you explicitly tell it not to. Easier than implementing it yourself.

**EDIT**

Now with more code!

I typically use the npm module `jsonwebtoken` for actually creating/signing my tokens, which has an option for setting expiration using friendly time offsets in the exp element of the payload.  It works like so:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

// in your login route
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  // do whatever you do to handle authentication, then issue the token:

  const token = jwt.sign(req.user, 's00perS3kritCode', { expiresIn: '30m' });
  res.send({ token });
});
```

Your JWT Strategy can then look like what you have already, from what I see, and it will automatically respect the expiration time of 30 minutes that I set above (obviously , you can set other times).

Comment: What are the best practices to extend the lifetime of token? For example, if a user wants to spend more than 30 minutes in the application?

Comment: This is done through what's commonly referred to as a 'refresh token', which basically means you ask for a new auth token against a specific endpoint.  The client application has to be proactive about this, usually.  More details: https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/

Comment: I added `expiresIn: '10s'` but doesn't work. Token is working after 10 seconds.

Comment: @iamcrypticcoder same, the token never expires

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following strategy to generate JWT-token with expiration limit of 1 hr.

```
let token = jwt.sign({
    exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + (60 * 60),
    data: JSON.stringify(user_object)
}, 'secret_key');
res.send({token : 'JWT '+token})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manipulate `expiresIn` with seconds

```
const { sign } = require('jsonwebtoken');

function generateToken(id) {
  const options = {
    expiresIn: 10, // seconds
    algorithm: 'RS256'
  };
  const payload = {
    sub: id,
    iat: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
  };
  return sign(payload, 'PRIVATE_KEY', options);
}
```

Answer (score -5):

I created a document in the database that stores the generated tokens and added an expiration date, when the user makes the request check if the token is expired or no.

**This is verify strategy that I used.**

```
/* ----------------------------- Create a new Strategy -------------------------*/
const strategy = new Strategy(params, (payload, done) => {

    const query = {
        token: jwtSimple.encode(payload, credentials.jwtSecret),
        expires: {$gt: new Date()}
    };

    TokenSchema.findOne(query, (err, result) => {
        if (err) done(err, null);
        if (!result) done(null, null);
        done(null, payload);
    });
});
passport.use(strategy);
/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

It's work for me.

Comment: If you're still doing that I would suggest to stop. You're missing the whole point of JWTs as they should be stateless.

Comment: Yeah exactly, bad practice here. Better alternatives for a stateful approach.

Comment: As stated previously, JWT are stateless and should not be stored in the database