# How can I modify the expiration timeout for the session

Tags: mongodb, express, passport.js, session-cookies

I need to modify the expiration timeout.
I am using passport for the login authentication and session storage.

Here is the mongodb atlas screenshot:

[image: session screenshot]

Comment: According to this answer, you can set it when configuring passport.js
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40187770/passport-jwt-token-expiration

Comment: Are you using `passport-jwt`  strategy?

Comment: yes Im using passport

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `express-session` to set/modify your cookie expiration time, and use `cookie.maxAge` property to set the `maxAge` a.k.a expiration time of your `cookie`.

Try this :

```
// you need to require express-session for it to work. 
var expressSession = require(express-session);

app.use(
    expressSession({
        secret: "your_Secret",
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        cookie : { maxAge : 3600000 } //1 hour (time is in milli seconds here)
    })
);

//initialize passport here
```

`Passport` needs session to be initialized for its session to work, i guess you must  be doing it, just add `cookie` field with `maxAge` there and it will work.

i hope this helps you out.

Comment: Can you show me how you are initializing passport and your app.js/server.js code